# count number of row matching patterns

Tags: r

I Have a data frame :

```
  df <- data.frame(sentences = c("An apple hangs on an apple tree",
                                 "Bananas are yellow and tasty",
                                 " Bananas and apples", 
                                 "The apple is tasty","Apples are healthy. Apples are juicy.",
                                 "Bananarama are an English female pop music vocal duo"
                                 ),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   

list_of_patterns <- tolower(c("Apple", "Banana")) # IMPORTANT : This list will contains thousand of patterns with real data
```

My result :

```
                       sentences
                      An apple hangs on an apple tree
                         Bananas are yellow and tasty
                                   Bananas and apples
                                   The apple is tasty
                Apples are healthy. Apples are juicy.
Bananarama are an English female pop music vocal duo
```

What I expected: I want to count the number of rows containing each word from my list of patterns. Not all patterns. (output DF).

```
Apple : 4 # number of rows containing this pattern
Banana : 3 # number of rows containing this pattern
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.

```
sapply(list_of_patterns, function(x) length(grep(x, df$sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)))
# apple banana 
#     4      3
```

## Tests

With large data sets my solution seems to be the fastest of the solutions posted ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62260148/8245406), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62260148/8245406)) so far. In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260054/count-number-of-row-matching-patterns/62260174#comment110114163_62260174), user [Daniel O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10442423/daniel-o) further improves on `sapply/length`. Specially for small data sets, `lengths` of a list members is faster.

```
library(microbenchmark)

Rui <- function(df){
  sapply(list_of_patterns, function(x) length(grep(x, df$sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)))
}
Rui2 <- function(df){
  lengths(sapply(list_of_patterns, grep, df$sentences, ignore.case = TRUE))
}
Ronak <- function(df){
  colSums(sapply(list_of_patterns, stringr::str_detect, string = tolower(df$sentences)) > 0)
}
GKi <- function(df){
  sapply(list_of_patterns, function(x) sum(grepl(x, tolower(df$sentences))))
}
GKi2 <- function(df){
  y <- tolower(df$sentences)
  sapply(list_of_patterns, function(x) sum(grepl(x, y)))
}

test <- function(df, n = 1){
  for(i in seq.int(n)) df <- rbind(df, df)
  mb <- microbenchmark(
    Rui = Rui(df),
    Rui2 = Rui2(df),
    Ronak = Ronak(df),
    GKi = GKi(df),
    GKi2 = GKi2(df)
  )
  print(mb, unit = 'relative', order = 'median')
}


test(df, 1)
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq        max neval cld
#  Rui2 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000000   100  a 
#   Rui 1.104683 1.095170 0.7443870 1.078442 1.065026 0.03807400   100  a 
#  GKi2 1.073707 1.109255 0.7726559 1.134426 1.097193 0.05178062   100  a 
#   GKi 1.396863 1.324172 0.9401923 1.334219 1.326366 0.05203571   100  a 
# Ronak 2.182422 2.160915 1.7950065 2.175393 2.962058 0.14150318   100   b
test(df, 10)
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
#  Rui2 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100 a   
#   Rui 1.067239 1.012265 1.017496 1.002532 1.001989 1.367107   100 a   
#  GKi2 1.622306 1.616520 1.673410 1.625944 1.627558 1.942846   100  b  
# Ronak 1.852324 1.756859 1.768850 1.718348 1.756507 1.637960   100   c 
#   GKi 2.519431 2.315098 2.325065 2.303203 2.347620 1.991377   100    d
```

Comment: according to the documentation, the `lengths( )` function is more efficient than `sapply(x, length)`. You might be able to shave some extra time implementing it. `lengths(sapply(list_of_patterns, grep, df$sentences, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_detect` from `stringr` :

```
colSums(sapply(list_of_patterns, stringr::str_detect, 
        string = tolower(df$sentences)))

# apple banana 
#     4      3
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. The sould be a df .

Comment: If you want output as dataframe, wrap `stack` or `data.frame` to the above?

Comment: Nice one @RonakShah! Using `str_detect` you could get rid of the `>0`

Comment: @DominikS.Meier Yes, I just realized that it is not important to count here actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grepl` with `sum` in `sapply`.

```
sapply(list_of_patterns, function(x) sum(grepl(x, tolower(df$sentences))))
# apple banana 
#     4      3
```

Or store the result of `tolower`

```
y <- tolower(df$sentences)
sapply(list_of_patterns, function(x) sum(grepl(x, y)))
```

Or using `colSums` like already @Ronak-Shah but in *base*:

```
colSums(sapply(list_of_patterns, grepl, tolower(df$sentences)))
```

Answer (score 0):

additional options

```
df <- df %>%  mutate(sentences = tolower(sentences))

list_of_patterns <- tolower(c("Apple", "Banana")) %>% purrr::set_names()

map_dbl(list_of_patterns, ~ sum(str_detect(df$sentences, .x)))
```